# @javascript cucumber tests pass using selenium driver but fail when using poltergiest

Tags: autocomplete, cucumber, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

I'm trying to test an jquery UI autocomplete, I've got the tests passing using the selenium driver. I want to switch to poltergiest for some headless testing, but now my tests are now failing.

It doesn't seem to select the autocomplete option for some reason that I have yet been able to figure out

**Step**

```
When /^select contract$/ do
  VCR.use_cassette("contract") do
    selector =
      '.ui-menu-item a:contains("John Smith (123456)")'
    within("div#review") do
      fill_in("contract", with: "john")
    end
    sleep 2
    page.execute_script "$('#{selector}').trigger(\"mouseenter\").click();"

    within("div#myPerformaceReview") do
      find_field("contract").value.should ==
        "John Smith (123456)"
    end
  end
end
```

The test passes using the Selenium driver without any changes to the step.

Any advice on how I could debug this?

**Version**

- selenium-webdriver (2.27.2)
- poltergeist (1.0.2)
- cucumber (1.2.1)
- cucumber-rails (1.0.6)
- capybara (1.1.4)
- phantomjs 1.8.1

Comment: At which row does this test fail?

Comment: when I assert that the field should hold the text from the autocomplete: find_field("contract").value.should == "John Smith (123456)". The page.execute_script does not seem to fire correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've managed to figure it out, it seems capybara-poltergeist driver doesn't trigger any of the events that jquery-ui uses to display the dropdown list.

I found the answer here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/50

I created a form helper in *features/support*

```
module FormHelper
  def fill_in_autocomplete(selector, value)
    page.execute_script %Q{$('#{selector}').val('#{value}').keydown()}
  end

  def choose_autocomplete(text)
    find('ul.ui-autocomplete').should have_content(text)
    page.execute_script("$('.ui-menu-item:contains(\"#{text}\")').find('a').trigger('mouseenter').click()")
  end
end
World(FormHelper)
```

I then used those method to fill in the form and select the desired option.

Answer (score 3):

Martin's answer almost worked for me, but I found that the input needs to be focused as well to make it work:

```
module FormHelper
  def fill_in_autocomplete(selector, value)
    page.execute_script %Q{$('#{selector}').focus().val('#{value}').keydown()}
  end

  def choose_autocomplete(text)
    find('ul.ui-autocomplete').should have_content(text)
    page.execute_script("$('.ui-menu-item:contains(\"#{text}\")').find('a').trigger('mouseenter').click()")
  end
end
```

Found this on the same page: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/50#issuecomment-4978108